# Storing cached values of a function as an attribute of the function in Python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I would like to have `@cached` decorator akin `@memoized`  that stores cached values of a function as an attribute of the function. Something like this

```
def cached(fcn):
    def cached_fcn(*args,**kwargs):
        call_signature=",".join([repr(a) for a in args] +
                                [repr(kwa[0])+"="+repr(kwa[1])
                                 for kwa in sorted(kwargs.items()) ])
        if call_signature not in cached_fcn.cache:
            cached_fcn.cache[call_signature] = fcn(*args,**kwargs)
        return copy.deepcopy(cached_fcn.cache[call_signature])
    cached_fcn.__name__ = fcn.__name__
    cached_fcn.__doc__ = fcn.__doc__
    cached_fcn.__annotations__ = fcn.__annotations__    
    cached_fcn.cache = dict()
    return cached_fcn

@cached
def fib(n):
    if n in (0,1): return 1
    return fin(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Assuming that the function does not access anything global, is it safe to do that? What if threading is used?

Comment: I don't see a problem with your implementation, just want to mention `functools.lru_cache` can achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one pitfall that may be relevant to your implementation. Observe

```
def pf(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
```

and call this with

```
pf(1, k="a")
pf(1, "a")
pf(k="a", x=1)
```

All argument specs are valid specs for a function with signature `f(x, k)` (with or without defaults) - so you can't really know the order of the arguments, their names, and sorting on `kwargs` is definitely not enough in a general case (empty in the second example, while `args` is empty in the last with order reversed). Defaults make this worse as if `f(x, k=3)` is the definition, then `f(2, 3)` and `f(2)` and `f(x=2)` `f(2, k=3)` and `f(x=2, k=3)` (also reversed) are the same, with differing `kwargs` and `args` passed to the wrapper.

A more robust solution will use [`inspect.getargspec(your_function)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec). This uses reflection to know the actual argument names of the function as they were defined. You then have to "fill in" the arguments your are given in `*args` and `**kwargs`, and use that to generate your call signature:

```
import inspect
def f(x, k=3): pass
argspec = inspect.getargspec(f) # returns ArgSpec(args=['x', 'k'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(3,))
```

Now you can generate a call signature (from `*args` and `**kwargs`):

```
signature = {}
for arg, default in zip(reversed(argspec.args), reversed(argspec.defaults)):
    signature[arg] = default

set_args = set()
for arg, val in zip(argspec.args, args):
    set_args.add(arg)
    signature[arg] = val

for arg, val in kwargs.items():
    # if arg in set_args:
    #    raise TypeError(f'{arg} set both in kwargs and in args!')
    # if arg not in argspec.args:
    #    raise TypeError(f'{arg} is not a valid argument for function!')
    signature[arg] = val

# if len(signature) == len(argspec.args):
#     raise TypeError(f'Received {len(signature)} arguments but expected {len(argspec.args)} arguments!')
```

Then you can use the dictionary `signature` itself as the call signature. I showed some "correctness" checks above though you may just want to let the call itself to the function detect and fail. I did not handle functions with `**kwargs` and `*args` (the actual used names are given in `argspec`). I think they may just involve having `args` and `kwargs` keys in `signature`. I am still not sure how robust the above is.

Even better, use the builtin [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) which does what you want.

**Regarding threading**, you have the same dangers as anytime multiple threads access the same array. There is nothing special about function attributes. `lru_cache` should be safe (there was one [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue28969) that was resolved) with the one caveat:

> To help measure the effectiveness of the cache and tune the maxsize
> parameter, the wrapped function is instrumented with a cache_info()
> function that returns a named tuple showing hits, misses, maxsize and
> currsize. In a multi-threaded environment, the hits and misses are
> approximate

Comment: Yes, I see this pitfall now. Thanks. I know that implementations exist. My question really is, is it save/robust to use custom function attributes for this sort of purposes. Another example would be, if I want to log all function calls together with some additional info, e.g. time spent in the call, etc. It's more like a question about using function attributes to collect info at runtime.

Comment: @R.Matveev In Python you can (and it's safe to) save whatever you want on any object you want. That's a very different question than what you asked.

Comment: @R.Matveev Regarding threading, you have the same pitfalls as when multiple threads are setting the same variable, there is nothing special about attributes on a functions.

Comment: Indeed, I did not formulate the question well. Your last two comments answer the intended question. Should one edit the question in this situation?

Comment: @R.Matveev No, that would be very disrespectful to all the work the answerers put (in this case only me). Better to ask a new question, which should be much more concise (no need to mention caches for example, or how you implemented them.) Thanks for asking and not just editing, that's not for-granted for new users at all.

Comment: @R.Matveev  Also, if this answers the actual original question, you can accept it to let future reader knows there is an answer for your question.